# How to pass array of objects to Class in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

```
export interface ICars{
    carType?: string;
    carColors: string[];
}

export class Cars implements ICars{
    carType?: string;
    carColors: string[];

    constructor(data?: ICars){
        //here code is present to set the carType and car Color parameters.
    }
}
```

And I am calling the above class from my react component as below.

```
const carTemplate: Cars = new  Cars({
    carType: myUseStateObjForCars,
    carColors: myUseStateArrayForCars,
})
```

My html is as follows

```
 const [myUseStateObjForCars, setMyUseStateObjForCars] = useState(0);
 const [myUseStateArrayForCars, setMyUseStateArrayForCars] = useState(0);

<input onChange={e=> setMyUseStateObjForCars(e.target.value)}
<input onChange={e=> setMyUseStateArrayForCars(e.target.value)}
```

This works fine when I have an Cars as a single object.
How can I achieve the same when I have to pass array of object to my Car class. Without modifying my class Cars by using any for loop or map to set every object inside my Cars class? 
I am using react hooks,Redux, RxJS and typescript.

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong here?
Any help on this would be appreciated as I am new to react.js , hooks and typesciprt.

```
[
    {
        carType: "4wheeler";
        carColors: ["red", "green"];        
    },
    {
        carType: "2wheeler";
        carColors: ["pink", "yellow"];  
    }
]
```

Comment: Typescript 1.8 / 2.0? Sure? We are at V3.9. Spamming tags is usually not appreciated on SO. If these weren't outdated tags you probably would have collected several downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `class Cars` shouldnt implement `ICars`, but if you want to implement it try this:

```js
export interface ICars{
    carType?: string;
    carColors: string[];
}

export class Cars implements ICars {
    carType?: string;
    carColors: string[];

    constructor(data?: ICars){
        //here code is present to set the carType and car Color parameters.
    }
}

// Add an extra class
export class CarList {
   private cars: Partial<Cars[]>;

   public constructor (cars: <Cars[]>) {
      this.cars = [];
   }

   public addCar (car: ICars) {
      this.cars.push(new Cars(carType: "Some value", ["red", "yellow"]));
   }
}
```

Remember you can instantiate an Object of the class Cars so each:
`const car = new Cars()`
refers to a single car, but the CarList has a cars property

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I wanted to know is there any other way without adding an extra class I can achieve that using the same >> ( export class Cars implements ICars ).
Class?

Like using some for loop or map function that will help me to set the objects inside the cars Class?

Comment: If no extra class is added, then you need to not implement ICars

```export interface ICars{
    carType?: string;
    carColors: string[];
}

export class Cars {
    private cars: Partial<ICars[]>;
    constructor(data: Partial<ICars[]>){
        this.cars = data.length > 0 ? [...data] : [];
    }

    public addCars (car: ICars) {
        this.cars.push({...car});
    }
}```

Comment: export interface ICars{ carType?: string; carColors: string[]; } export class Cars {
 private cars: Partial<ICars[]>; 
constructor(data: Partial<ICars[]>){ this.cars = data.length > 0 ? [...data] : []; } 
public addCars (car: ICars) { this.cars.push({...car}); } 
}
Remember you can instantiate an Object of the class Cars so each const car = new Cars() refers to a single car, but the CarList has a cars property